# require_once(/var/www/html/presta/var/cache/prod/appParameters.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, centos, prestashop

So like it's in the title I'm struggling with this error for a while now. Is there something helpful that I'm not doing or that is missing?

Error:

> PHP Warning: 
>   require_once(/var/www/html/presta/var/cache/prod/appParameters.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/presta/config/bootstrap.php on line 86

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, now the error that is showing is:

ncaught Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException: Unable to write to the "/var/www/html/presta/var/cache/prod/translations" directory. in /var/www/html/presta/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:681\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/presta/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/ResourceCheckerConfigCache.php(124): Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->dumpFile('/var/www/html/p...', 'write('dumpCatalogue('en-US', Object(Symfony\Component\Config\ConfigCache))\n#3 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator->Symfony\Component\Translation\{closure}(Object(Symfony\Component\Config\ConfigCache))\n in /var/www/html/presta/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Filesystem/Filesystem.php